# Javascript launching with (or without) document.writeln?

Tags: javascript, tags, tracking

I have been looking at some tracking issues and have a question pertaining to the launching of scripts. Can someone tell me if there is a difference between:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/universalPixel.html"></script>
```

and

```
<script language="JavaScript"> document.writeln('<scri' + 'pt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/universalPixel.html"></scri' + 'pt>');</script>
```

I have seen these two variations and unfortunately have not been able to discern if there is a significant difference dependent on the inclusion of the document.writeln method. Or perhaps another distinction that I am unaware of.

Thank you for your help.

Alex

Comment: The second one is just plain evil! ;) But seriously, don't use `document.write`. It's very 90's and horribly unmaintainable.

Answer (score 3):

`document.writeln` is probably used to dynamically include a script, using that strange string concatenation method because the browser processes `</script>` appearing anywhere as the end of the script tag, even inside of a JavaScript string.  So the following would not work correctly for that reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // code

    document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>");
    // ^^ the </script> above ends the previous <script> tag prematurely.

    // more code
</script>
```

But there are better methods:

1. Just include them normally, using `<script src="..">`
2. Dynamically generate includes using server-side code (i.e., PHP) instead of JavaScript
3. Use a JS library that provides dynamic library loading.

Answer (score 1):

Since document.writeLn is discouraged in XHTML, you should attempt to use option 1. Many strict browsers will even ignore the second item if the appropriate doctype is used.